# Incorrect results from A*/Path-finding algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, a-star

I'm trying to setup a path-finder in which I pass a maze (array of 1/0's with 1 being obstacles), start point/end point and for it to return the optimal path.

I have code from the following as my base, with the 'main' function modified as shown below. 
https://medium.com/@nicholas.w.swift/easy-a-star-pathfinding-7e6689c7f7b2

```
def main():
    maze = [[0,1,0,0,...],[0,0,0,0...],[...]...,[...]] #Example 2D List
    start = (4, 33)
    end = (200, 200)

    path = astar(maze, start, end)
    print(path)

#Create blank image for openCV
    img = np.zeros((221,221,3), np.uint8)
    x, y = 0, 0
    red = [0, 0, 255]

#Draw obstacles
    for row in maze:
        y+=1
        x=0
        for value in row:
            x+=1
            if value == 1: img[y, x]=red

#Draw path
    for x, y in path:
        img[y, x] = (255, 0, 0)

    cv2.imshow("Image", img)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Full maze used to make the map is here: https://pastebin.com/wT6dGQnj
this is a simplified case of a larger project, so list has been 'hard coded' here.

Below is the output, which seems to be incorrect as the path crosses multiple obstacles:
[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1wHi.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in how you're drawing the walls, not the path. You start with `y=1` and also seem to switch the x and y there.  I used the 10x10 maze in the original code, and things looked correct once I changed the wall-drawing part as follows:

```
n = 10
img = np.zeros((n,n,3), np.uint8)
x, y = 0, 0
red = [0, 0, 255]

# Draw the walls in red.  This is the part I changed.
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        if maze[i][j] == 1:
            img[i,j] = red

# Draw the path in blue
for x, y in path:
    img[x, y] = (255, 0, 0)
```

There's probably a more efficient way though you can map `maze` to `img` without doing two nested `for` loops like I did here.